# Robocopy switches to make new copies of existing files?

Tags: backup, robocopy, windows-backup

This is for a very basic backup plan.  Imagine that a full copy of c:/myfolder (and all its sub-folders) has already been created at d:/myfolder. Is it possible to use Robocopy as a daily/weekly job to:

- simply copy any new files to d:/myfolder, that is any files in C:/myfolder (and all its sub-folders) that aren't already in d:myfolder (and the corresponding sub-folders),
- but if a file in c:/myfolder/subfolder already exists in d:myfolder/subfolder, make a new copy in d:myfolder/subfolder with, for example, the date or an indexed version number appended to the filename

Comment: Yes to the first part. The second part is not supported by robocopy.

Comment: Yes, I'm discovering that the second objective is not reachable with Robocopy.  Thanks for confirming.  Just missing that one function.